Convergence of a Bayesian classifier
Background
Let $y_k$ be a noisy measurement at time $k$ and let $\{p_{k-1}(i)\}_{i=1}^n$ be (a discrete) prior probability distribution. Using Bayes rule, one can update the prior in function of $y_k$ according to
\begin{equation}
p_k(i)\triangleq \frac{\mathcal{L}(y_k|i)\,p_{k-1}(i)}{\sum_{j=1}^n \mathcal{L}(y_k|j)\,p_{k-1}(j)} \qquad i=1,\dots,n
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{L}(y_k|i)$ is some likelihood function. Then, we can repeat the process at time $k+1$ obtaining $\{p_{k+1}(i)\}_{i=1}^n$ in function of $y_{k+1}$, and so on for $k+2,k+3,\dots$
I would like to understand what happens as $k\to\infty$. My intuition says that if the likelihood is constant for every $k$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
\tag{1}
\mathcal{L}(y_k|i)=C_k \qquad \forall i=1,\dots,n
\end{equation*}
then no update at all is performed, in the sense that at every time we keep the initial distribution. More precisely, for every $j\in\mathbb{N}$
\begin{equation*}
p_{k+j}(i) =p_k(i) \qquad \forall i=1,\dots,n
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, I see from my numerical experiments that the probability distribution tends to converge to a Dirac distribution uniquely concentrated in a single class $i^*$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{k\to\infty} p_k(i)= \delta_{i^*}(i)
\end{equation*}
For what I've seen, this convergence is always true. Probably this is true because, due to noise, $(1)$ never happens.
Question

Excluding the singular case $(1)$, is it true that the posterior always converge to a Dirac distribution?

Excluding the singular case $(1)$, can the posterior converge to some probability distribution different from the starting one or a Dirac distribution?


